# Implicit conversion to lvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I'm looking at the standard 5.16 paragraph 3, trying to understand what is going on.  Consider the type `M` defined as

```
struct M {
  M();
  M(const M&);
  M(M&&);
};
```

If I have a ternary expression `pred ? E1 : E2`, where the type of `E1` is `const M&` and the type of `E2` is `M&&` does 5.16 paragraph 3 bullet 1 apply?

> — If E2 is an lvalue: E1 can be converted to match E2 if E1 can be implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the
>   type “lvalue reference to T2”, subject to the constraint that in the conversion the reference must bind
>   directly (8.5.3) to an lvalue.

I think it doesn't, because to have an implicit conversion to `const M&`, which requires `M` to have the member function `operator const M&()`.
However, I'm not sure, because it could be converted to `const M` implicitly, can the reference be implicitly added?

If it is implicitly convertible, does `M&&` bind directly to `const M&`?
I went through the procedure in 8.5.3, and I think that paragraph 5 bullet 2 is where this case falls, so it does bind directly, but I'm not certain.

> — If the initializer expression [..] has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be
>   implicitly converted to an xvalue, class prvalue, or function lvalue of type “cv3 T3”, where
>   “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3”

Comment: What is the definition of `T`?

Comment: Oh sorry, `T` should be `M`, I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Expressions don't have reference types. You mean `E1` is an lvalue of type `const M` and `E2` is an xvalue of type `M`. Does this change your question?

Comment: "can be implicitly converted" is defined in [conv]p3. It is more broad than just looking for conversion operators. In this case, `const M& x = std::declval<M&&>();` is well-formed, hence `M&&` (or, an xvalue of type `M`) is implicitly convertible to `const M&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have expressions of type `M&&`, instead it would be adjusted to be an *xvalue of type `M`*.

So the question is: if you have an xvalue of type `M`, can it be implicitly converted to lvalue reference to `const M`? The answer is yes, since a const lvalue reference can be initialized with an rvalue. Such a reference binding is direct since it falls under the following case:

> If the initializer expression
>   — is an xvalue (but not a bit-field), class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue and “*cv1* `T1`”
>   is reference-compatible with “*cv2* `T2`”, ...

rather than the last case that involves construction of a temporary, which is the indirect binding case.

Therefore this use of the conditional operator will be well-formed. The xvalue of type `M` will be converted to an lvalue of type `const M`. Then the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion will be applied and the result will be a prvalue of type `const M`.

Comment: So with `const M constM` and `M m`, the expression `false ? constM : std::move(m)` will take `m`, convert it to an lvalue of type `const M`, which will then be converted to a prvalue of type `const M`.  Finally, it will fall through to paragraph 6 where the result temporary, which is a prvalue of type `const M` gets copy initialized, which will in this case call the copy constructor?

Comment: @Nick Yes, that's my reading, so it's supposed to call the copy constructor twice: once to perform the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and once to initialize the result of the conditional expression. But my interpretation might be incorrect.